# How to read from os.Stdin repeatedly without shared bufio.Scanner

Tags: go

In Go, can a single line of input be read from stdin in a simple way, which also meets the following requirements?

- can be called by disparate parts of a larger interactive application without having to create coupling between these different parts of the application (e.g. by passing a global `bufio.Scanner` between them)
- works whether users are running an interactive terminal or using pre-scripted input

I'd like to modify an existing large Go application which currently creates a `bufio.Scanner` instance every time it asks users for a line of input. Multiple instances work fine when standard input is from a terminal, but when standard input is piped from another process, calls to `Scan` only succeed on the first instance of `bufio.Scanner`. Calls from all other instances fail.

Here's some toy code that demonstrates the problem:

```
package main
import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    // read with 1st scanner -> works for both piped stdin and terminal
    scanner1 := readStdinLine(1)
    // read with 2nd scanner -> fails for piped stdin, works for terminal
    readStdinLine(2)
    // read with 1st scanner -> prints line 2 for piped stdin, line 3 for terminal
    readLine(scanner1, 3)
}

func readStdinLine(lineNum int64) (scanner *bufio.Scanner) {
    scanner = readLine(bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin), lineNum)
    return
}

func readLine(scannerIn *bufio.Scanner, lineNum int64) (scanner *bufio.Scanner) {
    scanner = scannerIn
    scanned := scanner.Scan()
    fmt.Printf("%d: ", lineNum)
    if scanned {
        fmt.Printf("Text=%s\n", scanner.Text())
        return
    }
    if scanErr := scanner.Err(); scanErr != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error=%s\n", scanErr)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println("EOF")
    return
}
```

I build this as `print_stdin`and run interactively from a bash shell:

```
~$ ./print_stdin
ab
1: Text=ab
cd
2: Text=cd
ef
3: Text=ef
```

But if I pipe in the text, the second `bufio.Scanner` fails:

```
~$ echo "ab
> cd
> ef" | ./print_stdin
1: Text=ab
2: EOF
3: Text=cd
```

Comment: A Scanner buffers input.  Create a single scanner can call it multiple times to step through the lines. See [the Scanner (lines) example](https://godoc.org/bufio#example-Scanner--Lines) for a robust way to read from stdin.

Comment: @ThunderCat Yeah, I know that would work if all that was required was chugging though the input lines. The full program is interactive with different parts that can ask for user input as needed. Creating a new scanner each time user input is needed is a really easy way to handle this and works great with the terminal. It doesn't work, though, when users try to script their responses.

Comment: Use a package-level variable for the scanner If you don't want to pass the scanner around through your code.

Comment: @ThunderCat I'm not sure I can get the main author to accept a package-level variable. I've added more background info.

Comment: @ThunderCat You're right: using `bufio.Scanner` which buffers input is the real problem. Is there a simple way to read a line of input without using buffers?

Comment: The alternative to buffered read is reading a byte a time. Read single bytes until \n or some terminator is found and return the data up to that point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The suggestion in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50436786/how-to-read-from-os-stdin-repeatedly-without-shared-bufio-scanner#comment87894503_50436786) by [ThunderCat](http://stackoverflow.com/u/5728991) works.

> The alternative to buffered read is reading a byte a time. Read single bytes until \n or some terminator is found and return the data up to that point.

Here's my implementation, heavily inspired by [Scanner.Scan](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Scanner.Scan):

```
package lineio
import (
    "errors"
    "io"
)

const startBufSize = 4 * 1024
const maxBufSize = 64 * 1024
const maxConsecutiveEmptyReads = 100

var ErrTooLong = errors.New("lineio: line too long")

func ReadLine(r io.Reader) (string, error) {
    lb := &lineBuf {r:r, buf: make([]byte, startBufSize)}
    for {
        lb.ReadByte()
        if lb.err != nil || lb.TrimCrlf() {
            return lb.GetResult()
        }
    }
}

type lineBuf struct {
    r       io.Reader
    buf     []byte
    end     int
    err     error
}

func (lb *lineBuf) ReadByte() {
    if lb.EnsureBufSpace(); lb.err != nil {
        return
    }
    for empties := 0; ; {
        n := 0
        if n, lb.err = lb.r.Read(lb.buf[lb.end:lb.end+1]); lb.err != nil {
            return
        }
        if n > 0 {
            lb.end++
            return
        }
        empties++
        if empties > maxConsecutiveEmptyReads {
            lb.err = io.ErrNoProgress
            return
        }
    }
}

func (lb *lineBuf) TrimCrlf() bool {
    if !lb.EndsLf() {
        return false
    }
    lb.end--
    if lb.end > 0 && lb.buf[lb.end-1] == '\r' {
        lb.end--
    }
    return true
}

func (lb *lineBuf) GetResult() (string, error) {
    if lb.err != nil && lb.err != io.EOF {
        return "", lb.err
    }
    return string(lb.buf[0:lb.end]), nil
}

func (lb *lineBuf) EndsLf() bool {
    return lb.err == nil && lb.end > 0 && (lb.buf[lb.end-1] == '\n')
}

func (lb *lineBuf) EnsureBufSpace() {
    if lb.end < len(lb.buf) {
        return
    }
    newSize := len(lb.buf) * 2
    if newSize > maxBufSize {
        lb.err = ErrTooLong
        return
    }
    newBuf := make([]byte, newSize)
    copy(newBuf, lb.buf[0:lb.end])
    lb.buf = newBuf
    return
}
```

---

### TESTING

Compiled lineio with `go install` and main (see below) with `go build -o read_each_byte`.

Tested scripted input:

```
$ seq 12 22 78 | ./read_each_byte
1: Text: "12"
2: Text: "34"
3: Text: "56"
```

Tested input from an interactive terminal:

```
$ ./read_each_byte
abc
1: Text: "abc"
123
2: Text: "123"
x\y"z
3: Text: "x\\y\"z"
```

Here's main:

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
    "lineio"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    for i := 1; i <= 3; i++ {
        text, _ := lineio.ReadLine(os.Stdin)
        fmt.Printf("%d: Text: %q\n", i, text)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your sequence is:

1. create scanner
2. wait read terminal
3. print result
4. repeat 1 to 3 (creating new scanner about stdin)
5. repeat 2 to 3
6. exit program

When you exec echo in pipeline, only exists a stdin/stdout file being read/write, but you are trying to use two.

**UPDATE:** The flow of execution for echo is:

1. read args
2. process args
3. write args in stdout
4. terminal read stdout and print its

See that this occur on press ENTER key. The argument whole is sent to echo program and not by line.

> The echo utility writes its arguments to standard output, followed by
>   a . If there are no arguments, only the  is written.

More here: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html.

See in [source code](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/echo.c) how echo work:

```
while (argc > 0) 
{
  fputs (argv[0], stdout);//<-- send args to the same stdout
  argc--;
  argv++;
  if (argc > 0)
    putchar (' ');
}
```

So your code will work fine with this:

```
$ (n=1; while sleep 1; do echo a$n; n=$((n+1)); done) | ./print_stdin 
$ 1: Text=a1
$ 2: Text=a2
$ 3: Text=a3
```

If you need repeat args in differents stdout, use "yes" program or alternatives.
**yes** program repeats the wrote args in stdout. More in:
https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/yes.c

Example:

```
$ yes a | ./print_stdin 
$ 1: Text=a
$ 2: Text=a
$ 3: Text=a
```

Comment: I know there's only one stdin. If I run something like `seq -w 1 1000 | ./main`, then I get `1: Text: 0001` `2: Text: 820` `3: Text:0003`. I guess the problem is that the first Scanner instance reads a large portion of stdin instead of just a single line.

Comment: The technique you're suggesting - piping text into the Go application line-by-line with delays between the lines - is a really clever workaround to this problem with the `Scanner`. It has the drawback that users would need to script both the input they need **and** the timing that input needs to be provided (and timing will vary e.g. depending on what else is running on the same machine), but still in many cases it's a viable way to script input without fixing the application itself. Nice!